# How do I check if page has certain ID

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

I have a page that needs to behave a little different than similair pages, so I want to add an if else statement for only one ID. How can I do that for magento 1.9?

On the view.phtml I need to add something like:

```
if($pageid == 44){
    echo 'do this';
}
```

What do I add for `$pageid` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an **URL parameter** you can use

```
$pageId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('pageid', 0)
```

**For** [category](/questions/tagged/category) **pages:**

```
$pageId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()
```

You can also modify your single category from `your_layout.xml` Layout handles for categoris look like:

```
<CATEGORY_{yourId}>
    <reference ...
```

**For CMS pages:**

```
$pageId = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getId() // use getIdentifie‌​r()
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I needed. I will accept your answer when I can in 4 minutes.